# How to add default value and alias using ES6 de-structuring?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have a specific use case where I want to do a nested de-structuring and assign an alias (rename it to another variable name, say `aliasD`) as well as a default value to a property. E.g.

```
const a = { b: { c: [{ d: 'value' }] } };
```

and while destructuring I only need `d` but with an alias `aliasD` and a default value `defaultVal`. SO I tried below, but I am not sure what I am missing

```js
const a = { b: { c: [{ d: 'value' }] } };
const { b: { c: [first: { d: aliasD = defaultVal }] } } = a;

console.log(aliasD);
```

But this doesn't work

Comment: Can you show what you start with and what you want to end up with?  That is not clear to me.

Comment: Why is there `first` there?

Comment: @jfriend00 Doesn't the first line of the question clarify that I want to destructure with an alias and also a default value? Not sure what else you looking for?

Comment: @AndrewLi I was trying to alias first item of array. But guess that's not needed.

Comment: @AdityaSingh no it's not...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what "destructure with an alias" means.  Showing the before and after data structures would make it completely clear to all what you're trying to achieve.  In the future, when people ask for a specific clarification, it's because they don't follow what you have already written so just pointing them to that isn't likely to help them help you.

Comment: Yeah. Looking at @lucas answer below, it makes sense to remove it

Comment: @jfriend00 I guess you need to refer this then http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html. Specifically `let { first: f, last: l } = obj;`

Comment: Uhh, the word "alias" does not appear in that article at all.  You seem to have made up a term that means something to you, but is not clear to me and all I asked for was a code example of before and after so I could see what you meant by that.  Never mind, I will leave now since you don't appear to care to make your question as clear as it could be.

Comment: Yeah. I guess I assumed that you use the variable renames/alias/shortnames like me. I think that sometimes we should not stick with keywords. This would then make sense to relate `alias` as a ES6  functionality and not keyword :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is for destructuring the array, the correct syntax to get the first value of the array would be:

```
[varName] = yourArray
```

Applying that to your example:

```
const { b: { c: [{ d: aliasD = 'test' }] } } = a;
```

You can try it out with [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=const%20a%20%3D%20%7B%20b%3A%20%7B%20c%3A%20%5B%7B%20d%3A%20'value'%20%7D%5D%20%7D%20%7D%0A%0Aconst%20%7B%20b%3A%20%7B%20c%3A%20%5B%7B%20d%3A%20aliasD%20%3D%20'test'%20%7D%5D%20%7D%20%7D%20%3D%20a%3B)

Comment: I guess I added extra quotes for default but looking at your answer , it makes sense for the array destructuring.

Comment: @AdityaSingh actually I misread your code. The only problem was the array destructuring. I'll edit my answer